# Why doesn't the first navigationcontroller in my storyboard have an effect on the tableviewcontroller?

Tags: swift, xcode

My Storyboard is setup as:

```
                                                    UIViewCont 
                                                   /
NavigationController -> UIViewContr -> UIViewContr ----- UIView Contr
                                                  \ 
                                                   NavCont
                                                     \
                                                    TableViewController
```

The last three controllers (2 x UIView and 1 x TableView) use "show" segues from three different buttons. And the TableView controller is embedded in the NavCont.

Because the first controller is a NavController every UIViewController has a back button except the TableViewController.

I've been reading up about it but can't figure out why. Other than each Navigation controller is it's own stack and kind of starts again so you can't just navigate back from a 2nd or 3rd navigation controller. But not sure.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a navigation controller resets the navigation stack tracking, so your table view does not have a back button because it is effectively a new root. If you create a view controller that the table view segues to, it will have a back button because it is part of the (inner) navigation chain and not the root.

It is not apparent from your example what you are trying to do or why you have the inner navigation controller instead of just relying on the original navigation stack. There is one option you can try. The root view of a navigation stack should have the navigation bar, and you can drag bar button items onto it, allowing you to unwind back to the previous state.

Comment: thanks. i mistakenly thought that to have a master-detail the tableviewcontroller needed to be embedded in a navigation controller but i'm wrong. thx.